# Android keyboard resizes when changing letter casing

Tags: keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4

I've Nexus 4 with latest update. When I type something, when typing capital letters, keyboard size is almost twice bigger than when typing small letters and it's confusing because when I start the sentence, I have to type first letter (capital) and then wait a little to click on small letter (because its position changes as key sizes change). Is it possible to "fix" the keys sizes?

UPD: This ONLY happens with Russian keyboard... Attached screenshots.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: Are you using the default Android keyboard? Does this happen in all applications? I also have the Nexus 4 with latest update, but have not experienced this.

Comment: Yes, that's default keyboard. When I click "shift", the size of the keyboard changes (keys get bigger when switched to capital letters).

Comment: Bryan, attached screenshots.

Comment: This behavior is really weird. Perhaps it is caused by unicode fonts with fixed height that the keyboard can't trim causing it to look enlarged. Try changing your default font with ROM manager if you are already rooted.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem suddenly with UK keyboard quertyuiop. Nexus 4 latest android.

The solution was to power down the phone and start again. All back to normal now.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en) instead it's the best I've used.

Comment: The Hackers Keyboard is great - I use it on my tablet. However, I also use the default Android keyboard on my Nexus 4 (Android 4.2) and this works great also. I particularly like the swipe input (new with 4.2) which is awesome. However, I don't think recommending another keyboard is necessarily a desirable solution in this instance where there does appear to be a genuine problem. (I didn't downvote you btw.)

Comment: Yeah, alternative keyboards will help, I tried GO Keyboard, it works great. But still I like the default one, others are too overloaded with features.

Comment: I agree with @Tareq in the use of an alternate keyboard, although I prefer [Swiftkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=en).  My children have the default keyboard on the Nexus 7 tablets, and it drives me nuts when I have to fix something.  Especially not being able to long press for number but having to switch to a different keyboard entirely.  Of course, it's still easier than inputting a 64-bit WPA2 passcode into a [Nest thermostat](http://nest.com/). :-)